# Trying to get property of non-object on sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SET @rank=0; SELECT receivedData.* FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, ID FROM data ORDER BY Eindtijd ASC) AS receivedData ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

When I run this on my phpmyadmin on my server everything works fine.

But when I run it with php I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT receivedData.* FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, ID FROM data ORDER BY' at line 1

```
$sql2 = "SET @rank=0; SELECT receivedData.* FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, ID FROM data ORDER BY Eindtijd ASC) AS receivedData ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
 $result = $conn->query($sql2) or die($conn->error);
```

I really don't get why it doesn't work in php

Comment: You have to execute those in two different commands.

Comment: try using backticks `` around table and column names and quotations '' around values. Its possible that the database doesn't know which is which.

Comment: @PatrickQ how would that work?

Comment: Try to execute your query separately.

Comment: @PatrickQ is right, a first query to set your rank variable, a second one to execute your real sql

Comment: It's is also possible to set user_variables into a SELECT statement with a CROSS JOIN.. i've posted a query on how to do that. making it one query instead of two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Patrick has suggested you could try:

```
$sSQL = "SET @rank=0;";

if($conn->query($sSQL)){
    $sSQL = "SELECT receivedData.* FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, ID FROM data ORDER BY Eindtijd ASC) AS receivedData ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
    $conn->query($sSQL);
}
```

`$conn->query()` will only execute one command at a time. From manual:
" PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object."

Because you are reusing the connection the query should still have access to the local var.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Comment: your welcome, if this resolved your issue please mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: Whoops, sorry..

Answer (score 1):

You can combine those two queries.

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT
  receivedData.*
FROM (
  SELECT
     @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
    , ID
  FROM
   data
  ORDER BY
   Eindtijd ASC
 )
   AS receivedData
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Into

```
SELECT
  receivedData.*
FROM (
  SELECT
     @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
    , ID
  FROM
   data
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) as init_user_param
  ORDER BY
   Eindtijd ASC
 )
   AS receivedData
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With `PDO` you can do this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', 'password');

$statement = $db->prepare('SET @rank = "1";  SELECT receivedData.* FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, ID FROM data ORDER BY Eindtijd ASC) AS receivedData ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;');

$statement->execute();

do {
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($data);

} while ($statement->nextRowset());
```

The first returned array will be empty as there is nothing to return from the first query. The second returned array will hold your data.